# mysql: apostrophe not being read from varchar column in database?

Tags: php, mysql, apostrophe

i have the following table for new_supplier_request:

```
Id  |  ref  |  User   |  Manager (Varchar)
1      12      James     Henry O'Brien
```

I also have my internal_users table:

```
 Id  |    User_firs_name   |  user_last_name(Varchar)    
 1        Henry               O'Brien
```

i am using the following mysql query to give a manager permission (who is logged in) to view some content if the managers name appears for that row of data in the manager column of my new_supplier_request table

```
$_SESSION['username'] = internal_users.user_first_name
$_SESSION['username2'] = internal_users.user_last_name
$user = $_SESSION['username']." ".$_SESSION['username2'];

$sql34 = "select * from new_supplier_request, internal_users where new_supplier_request.status!= 'complete' and new_supplier_request.action_taken ='none' AND new_supplier_request.user_id = internal_users.user_id AND requestee_manager = '$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql34);
```

For some reason this works fine if the last name does not contain an apostrophe, but because this managers last name is O'Brien for some reason when i check in my query it is failing because it is having difficulty reading the apostrophe in the name, if i change henry's last name to something like James then it works. can someone please explain what i am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: You're using MySQLi, so learn to use bind variables.... then you don't need to worry about escaping special characters like quotes

Comment: That's what you get when you don't use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, internal_users.user_first_name);
$_SESSION['username2'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, internal_users.user_last_name);
```

Comment: you should suggest the use of prepared statements instead of string escaping, really.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)'s prepared statements with bound parameters.

This way, your requests would be safer and a lots of problem with string parameters should be solved.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('
select *
from new_supplier_request, internal_users
where new_supplier_request.status <> :status
and new_supplier_request.action_taken = :action_taken
AND new_supplier_request.user_id = internal_users.user_id
AND requestee_manager = :user
');

$query->bindValue(':status', 'complete');
$query->bindValue(':action_taken', 'none');
$query->bindValue(':user', $user);

$query->execute();

$results = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: mysqli has a similar approach for prepared statements

Comment: I totally agree with you, but PDO is according to me more easy to use (and read) with usage of named parameters and prepared statements. It's also more flexible, but that's not the topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$conn->real_escape_string($user)` instead of `$user` in the query. You should NEVER use variable values directly in the query without enforcing a type or escaping them as you will leave the code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

[image]